# Deploy and load a picture to use as a texture in a holographic app

Tags: visual-c++, uwp, hololens

I created a sample holographic application in Visual Studio 2015 with C++/CX (or whatever they call that fancy C++ with hats and ref new). It builds, deploys and runs fine, rendering a rotating colored cube, just as it's supposed to. Now I am trying to add a jpeg image and use it as a texture on the cube. The question is, where shall I put the image, how do I add it to the project, how do I make VS to deploy it along with the rest of the project, and how do I load it in my application?

I have literally zero experience with both DirectX and UWP. I've done [this tutorial on textures](https://www.braynzarsoft.net/viewtutorial/q16390-11-textures) on my desktop Windows 10 (a regular C++ app, not managed, not UWP), although the way they load a file into a texture in the tutorial didn't work for me. After some googling I downloaded [this library](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex), built it for desktop Windows 10 (`DirectXTex_Desktop_2015_Win10.sln`) and used in my project as follows:

```
DirectX::ScratchImage image;
LoadFromWICFile(L"myimage.jpg", DirectX::WIC_FLAGS_NONE, nullptr, image);
CreateShaderResourceView(d3d11Device, image.GetImages(), image.GetImageCount(), image.GetMetadata(), &CubesTexture);
```

It worked. Now, for Hololens I built their `DirectXTex_Windows10.sln` solution (assuming that if the other one was for desktop, this one must be for non-desktop) and tried (unsuccessfully) using it like this:

```
DirectX::ScratchImage image;
HRESULT hr = LoadFromWICFile(L"ms-appx:///myimage.jpg", DirectX::WIC_FLAGS_NONE, nullptr, image);
CreateShaderResourceView(m_deviceResources->GetD3DDevice(), image.GetImages(), image.GetImageCount(), image.GetMetadata(), &m_cubesTexture);
```

I also tried `ms-appdata` instead of `ms-appx`. In both cases `LoadFromWICFile` does not return `S_OK`. It gives `ERROR_INVALID_NAME: The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect.` As for `myimage.jpg`, I put it into the `Assets` subfolder and added to the solution through `Add->Existing Item`. Is that enough to get it deployed to Hololens? How do I check if it gets deployed? Where on the device is it going to be located, if deployed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I over-complicated things.

To add a file like that into a project, simply use `right click` (on the `Assets` sub-folder in the solution explorer) `-> Add -> Existing Item`. To get it deployed on the device or emulator, `right click` on the file `-> Properties`, set `Content` to `Yes` and `Item Type` to `Image` or `Does not participate in build` (for something that doesn't get recognized correctly, for example, Wavefront .OBJ file, which VS would otherwise try and fail to link).

To check if (and where) the file is going to be on the device or emulator, you can build an actual package: right click on the project, choose `Store->Create App Packages...` It creates an `.appx` file, which is actually a zip-archive. You can explore it with an archiver like 7zip, or rename it from `.appx` to `.zip` and open with Windows File Explorer. In my case the image file was there, in the `Assets` subfolder. I was able to read it by its simple relative path, like this (no `ms-appx:///` or other such prefixes):

```
HRESULT hr = LoadFromWICFile(L"Assets/myimage.jpg", DirectX::WIC_FLAGS_NONE, nullptr, image);
```

For some other functions (`std::fopen`, `std::ifstream` etc.) this relative path didn't work, I had to use the full path as follows:

```
Platform::String^ appInstallFolder = Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current->InstalledLocation->Path;
std::wstring folderNameW(appInstallFolder->Begin());
std::string folderNameA(folderNameW.begin(), folderNameW.end());
std::string fname = folderNameA + std::string("/Assets/model.obj");
std::FILE *f = std::fopen(fname.c_str(), "r");
```

Answer (score 1):

This textured cube project might give you some insight. I think is based on the C# VS2015 Holographic template.

https://github.com/dngoins/HololensDXTutorials